# Electric field inside a cavity in non conducting sphere

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

Why electric field inside a concentric cavity in non conducting sphere is zero but not in non concentric cavity ?

Answer (score 1):

The electric field inside a spherical cavity is dependent on the distance between the centre of sphere of which the cavity is a part, and the centre of cavity.

That distance is zero for a concentric cavity, hence field strength is also zero. That’s not the case for a non concentric cavity.

I’d also like to point out here, that the field strength inside a cavity is constant in direction and magnitude, at all the points of the cavity. So no matter how large the concentric spherical cavity is, the field strength inside it is zero at all points.

Comment: Can you pls tell how electric field is dependent on distance between the centre of sphere and centre of cavity

Comment: You can derive the expression by considering the sphere to have a positive charge density and the cavity to have a negative charge density of equal magnitude. Say you want to find it at a point P inside the cavity. Assume the centre of sphere as origin. Let the position vector of P be r1, the vector joining centre of cavity to P be r2 and position vector of centre of cavity be d. Electric field at point P is resultant of that due to sphere of positive charge density and cavity of negative charge density. Just write the expression and use triangle law of addition of vectors. You’ll get it.

Comment: But according to gauss law shouldn't the electric field be zero as charge enclosed is zero just like in the case of inside hollow sphere

Comment: Gauss’ law only says that the flux is zero. That doesn’t guarantee the field strength is zero. The dot product of electric field strength vector and the are vector can be zero even if the electric field strength vector is non zero.

Comment: So why inside hollow sphere  electric field is zero                          as our teacher used gauss law to prove that inside hollow sphere as charge enclosed is zero so electric field is zero